# Controller ask to download on entry

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I tring to use the simple Get function in web api 2,
in the controller i creating an instance of object that i get from referenced dll but instead of entering the get and work with the object its ask me to download it for exmp : localhost:6969/api/Test ask me to download Test

what i'm doing wrong

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{

    public string Get()
    {
        MyObject obj = new MyObject();
        string getText = MyObject.Getsomething();

        return getText;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try using a different Browser, i get that when im testing my API on my server with Internet Explorer.

Comment: @JoachimGotzes i will try, thanks

Comment: @JoachimGotzes in chrome browser it's give me more info about the exception, thanks

Comment: try using postman, It's great for testing APIs - https://www.getpostman.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be because your browser of choice doesn't understand what you do with the given `Content-Type` that has been returned back from the API.

Try using something like [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to test your API, It's a lot more flexible than using a browser.

Comment: i already solved it (it was missing assembly dependence only in chrome i get the exception)